all programs installed via snap doubled
Previously I changed from bash to zsh. And after restarting, programs installed via snap didn't open. I found a solution here, but after copying, I got duplicate programs.
If I try to delete .desktop from /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/ nothing changes. I still have duplicated programs.
Example 1:

Example 2:

